# Como controlar um player SWF (Flash) via Parâmetros <param> HTML?

Tags: html

> Possuo um player para `streaming de áudio` e gostaria de deixá-lo mais fácil de mudar os dados do servidor (IP e Porta). **[Baixar](https://www.sendspace.com/file/vxxxjn)**

Atualmente eu utilizo o software grátis [**SWiX**](http://ziggi.uol.com.br/downloads/swix) para editar os dados do **Player**.

> Os dados (IP e PORTA) ficam na linha **DoAction**:

[image]

---

Só que queria editar apenas usando os parâmetros, semelhante ao site abaixo:

http://www.radiovibracaoweb.com.br/player

Ele utiliza da seguinte forma:

```
    <object width=180 height=70 style="float: left;margin-top: 5px;">
        <param name=movie value="http://paineladmin.com/swf/player_novo.swf" />
        <param name=allowfullscreen value=true />
        <param name=allowscriptaccess value=always />
        <param name=wmode value=transparent />
        <param name=flashVars value="rtmp=rtmp://192.198.204.194:1935/stream&servidor=http://centova.ehostsolucoes.com.br:8516" />
        <embed wmode="transparent" src="http://paineladmin.com/swf/player_novo.swf" type=application/x-shockwave-flash allowscriptaccess=always allowfullscreen=true width=180 height=70 flashvars="rtmp=rtmp://192.198.204.194:1935/stream&servidor=http://centova.ehostsolucoes.com.br:8516" />
        </embed>
    </object>
```

[**EXEMPLO NO JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/AlexandreBR/vLjp64z6/)

Como posso fazer algo semelhante a isso com o meu Player?

Também aceito sugestões com Javascript / jQuery

Answer (score 1):

Caso possa trocar o player SWF, talvez seja interessante mudar para uma solução em HTML, o único problema (que já nem é tão grande assim) são os navegadores que não derem suporte ao codec de audio que você utilizar.

Com uma solução HTML5, você pode realizar todos os controles via JavaScript puro.
[Aqui neste post](http://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/article/streaming-audio-and-video-with-html-5) tem o seguinte exemplo de como fazer isso:

```
<video width="356" height="200" controls poster="full/http/link/to/image/file.png">
    <source src="full/link/to/http/mp4/video/file.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
    <source src="full/link/to/http/ogv/video/file.ogv" type="video/ogg" />
    <source src="full/link/to/http/webm/video/file.wbem" type="video/webm" />
    <em>Sorry, your browser doesn't support HTML5 video.</em>
</video>
```

Comment: Oi, Lucas, normalmente é legal colocar um sumário quando citamos algum material externo. Coloquei o exemplo de código já que o conteúdo do link é basicamente isso. Espero que não se importe e fique a vontade para mudar minha edição se desejar. . . . O que seria interessante é fazer um *fallback* HTML pro SWF, ou ao contrário um *fallback* SWF pro HTML.